# Prefix each line of a CSV with a Number

Tags: powershell, csv

I have inherited a PS script that takes some data from a CSV, formats it into something that the system can digest and then dumps it back to another CSV.  So, I don't fully understand it; thus, I don't know exactly where to inject my desired code/changes.  It's a horrible system but it's what we have for now.  Below is what the script currently pulls in, manipulates and then spits out.

**import.csv**

```
Name,Number
John Smith,(555)123-4567
Jane Smith,(555)123-4567
Todd Smith,(555)123-4567
```

As I mentioned, it spits out another CSV that gets imported into said terrible system...

**current_output.csv**

```
Name,Number
JohnSmith,5551234567
JaneSmith,5551234567
ToddSmith,5551234567
```

The [inherited] code that does that, is below:

```
$CSVDATA = import-csv *.csv
$people = @()

Foreach($person in $CSVDATA){
    $namepattern = '[^a-zA-Z]'
    $numberpattern = '[^0-9]'
    if($person.Name -ne "" -and $person.Number -ne ""){
        $people += $myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $($person.Name -replace $namepattern,'')
            Number = $($person.Number -replace $numberpattern,'')
        }
    }
}

$counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 }
$groupSize = 40000
$people = $people | where {$_.number -ne ""}
$groups = $people | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $groupSize) }

foreach($group in $groups){
    $group.group | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter "," -Path "..\Processed\$($group.name)-$(get-date -Format yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
    $File = "..\Processed\$($group.name)-$(get-date -Format yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
    (Get-Content $File) | Foreach-Object {
        $_ -replace "`"", ""
    } | Set-Content $File
}
```

I would like to prefix each line with the line number while padding it with zeroes so things *line up* in certain views.  As I mentioned, I didn't write the script so I don't know exactly where to inject what is needed to create the desired output below.

**desired_output.csv**

```
Name,Number
0001JohnSmith,5551234567
0002JaneSmith,5551234567
0003ToddSmith,5551234567
```

Comment: the prefixes should start from 0001 for each chunk file or continue from the previous chunk?

Comment: Strongly recommend including a name in the header and a comma after the line number. That will allow many existing systems to continue processing it correctly. But the problem you have right now is you need to read and load the entire file to know how many lines you have, in order to know how much padding to use. That could significantly hurt performance.

Comment: Is the problem you're trying to solve adding a number to the start of the line, or is it being able to identify the line *somehow* in a later stage?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'chunk' but, in our current_output.csv file, we may have 4000 lines.  I'd like each one to be prefixed with the a sequential number.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm trying to figure out how to get the numbers in place.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the system into which these files eventually get imported, is a real piece of work! It's horrible to work with.  It's buggy!  It's the temperamental.  However, it's what we have so it's not going anywhere. As for the performance, I do this sort of work every month or so on my machine so it's not like a server is being banged on every minute by some automated task. In my mind, the code could count the number of lines in the file, subtract one for the header and that would be how it knew how far to prefix the lines.

Comment: `$group.group | Export-Csv....` is exporting a chunk of `40000` Csv lines to different files, thats what I meant by chunk

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I wondered what that part of the code did.  I have never ended up with more than one file so I never knew.  That said, the individual files can only be worked with, within the final [buggy] system, one at a time so, the numbering can start over with each file.

Comment: yes, that logic is meant to split up files in chunks of 40000 Csv lines but the logic itself is extremely complicated, could be so much more simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a bunch of comments to hopefully help you follow the logic of the code but it might be a bit complicated to follow. Using the `List<T>` is much better than the logic you have in place with `Group-Object` to output chunks of objects to each CSV.

```bash
$csvdata = Import-Csv *.csv
$namepattern = '[^a-zA-Z]'
$numberpattern = '[^0-9]'
# this list is used to collect objects before outputting to a file
$chunk = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
# this variable determines how many objects to collect before outputting to a file
$groupSize = 40000
# this variable is used in the file name, before the hyphen (Processed\1-...., Processed\2-...., etc)
$idx = 1
# this variable is to add the numbers before the Names
$padding = 1
# this is the path that will be used to output each file, `{0}` gets replaced with the number in `$idx` later on
$File = "..\Processed\{0}-$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

foreach ($person in $csvdata) {
    if ($person.Name -eq '' -or $person.Number -eq '') {
        continue
    }

    # add the new object to the list
    $chunk.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
        # `($padding++).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')` means that the number in `$padding` gets incremented by 1
        # on each loop iteration and at the same time its outputted and concatenated with the `.Name` using zero padding
        Name   = ($padding++).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ($person.Name -replace $namepattern)
        Number = $person.Number -replace $numberpattern
    })

    # if the list has the same number of objects as the `$groupSize` variable
    if ($chunk.Count -eq $groupSize) {
        # create a new path incrementing `$idx` (-f injects the value of `$idx` in `{0}`)
        $path = $File -f $idx++
        # convert the chunk of objects to a Csv and remove all quotes `"`
        ($chunk.ToArray() | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"' |
            # output that to the new path
            Set-Content $path
        # clear the list
        $chunk.Clear()
        # and reset the padding variable
        $padding = 1
    }
}

# if there are any remaining objects in the list
if ($chunk.Count) {
    # follow the same process as before
    $path = $File -f $idx++
    ($chunk.ToArray() | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"' |
        Set-Content $path
    $chunk.Clear()
}
```

If you wanted to have a CSV with 3 columns and have that index in its own column, which would be advisable, you should change:

```bash
$chunk.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
    Name   = ($padding++).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ($person.Name -replace $namepattern)
    Number = $person.Number -replace $numberpattern
})
```

To:

```bash
$chunk.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
    Index  = ($padding++).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')
    Name   = $person.Name -replace $namepattern
    Number = $person.Number -replace $numberpattern
})
```

Comment: that worked out well.  I wouldn't have an issue with a 3rd column but, the system we're working with is buggy and can only use the NAME & NUMBER columns.  I have a ticket open with their support, complaining about the many issues but, I am hoping this code will relieve some stress.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RKillcrazy np! glad it was helpful